# Query in Oracle to select with subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, constraints

I have the following table on my Oracle database:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
 flight NUMBER(4),
 date   DATE,
 action VARCHAR2(50),
 CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (flight,date)
);
```

and the following registers:

```
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO test VALUES ('1234', '2020-02-29 18:00', 'Departure');
 INSERT INTO test VALUES ('1234', '2020-02-29 19:00', 'Arrival');

 INSERT INTO test VALUES ('4321', '2020-02-20 22:00', 'Departure');
 INSERT INTO test VALUES ('4321', '2020-02-21 04:30', 'Arrival');
END;
/
```

My problem is that I want to make a SELECT that returns me the flight number only when it has departed and arrived at the same day. For example, flight '1234' has departed on day 29 and arrived on day 29, but in the other hand, the flight '4321' has departed on day 20 and arrived on day 21. I only would like to select the flight '1234', because it is the only one who meets the requeriments.

I have been thinking about the following select, but it doesn't work because the subquery returns more than just one value:

```
SELECT flight
  FROM test
 WHERE action = 'Departure'
   AND TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = (SELECT TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                                        FROM test
                                       WHERE action = 'Arrival');
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: It is common for flight numbers to be re-used. Can it happen in your data model, too, that two different flights have the same flight number or does a flight number uniquely identify a flight in your table?

Comment: Btw, you don't need a `to_char()` conversion among dates as in your case. If there exists an index on date column, the impact of index would be killed by such a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You just need distinct action within a day. So, use HAVING count distinctly of two individual actions GROUPed BY flight and day :

```
SELECT flight
  FROM test
 WHERE action in ('Departure','Arrival')
 GROUP BY flight, trunc("date")
HAVING COUNT(distinct action)=2
```

where there should be `distinct` clause, need is observed if the sample data set is extended

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e688246618dfec0416d79d735589311c)</kbd>

- *`date` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as a column name for Oracle database. So, I preferred `"date"`*
- *Prefix the time literals with `timestamp` keyword and add portion `:00` at the end to represent `second` such as `timestamp'2020-02-21 04:30:00'` during the insertion*

Answer (score 1):

We don't know, whether a flight number in your data model uniquely represents a flight or not. We also don't know whether there can be any actions apart from 'Departure' and 'Arrival'.

The following solutions look at a flight number in combination with the flight date and consider the two actions in question, so they work in any case:

### With `INTERSECT`:

```
select flight, trunc(date) from test where action = 'Departure'
intersect
select flight, trunc(date) from test where action = 'Arrival';
```

### With aggregation:

```
select flight, trunc(date)
from test
group by flight, trunc(date)
having count(case when action = 'Departure' then 1 end) = 1
   and count(case when action = 'Arrival' then 1 end) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  the same table two time in join

```
SELECT t1.flight
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN test t2 ON t1.action = 'Departure'
    AND TO_CHAR(t1.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')  = TO_CHAR(t2.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND t2.action = 'Arrival'
    AND t1.flight =t2.flight
```

Or using the subquery  ..use a proper FROM clause again

```
SELECT flight
FROM test
WHERE action = 'Departure'
AND (TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), flight)  = (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), flight
    FROM test
    WHERE action = 'Arrival');
```

Comment: but the last select would not work, because the subquery will return all the dates of all the flights' arrivals.

Comment: yes  ..but the with main query the  where condition should return only the matching rows ..  alias the fligth where departure and arrival have the sam time . .. in youy query you use the result forma query for match a where condition ...  .. chekc better because the two query return the same result

Comment: imagine that 2 flies have the same date. It would not work as you are only comparing dates, and the primary key is flight + date

Answer (score 0):

With `COUNT()` window function:

```
select distinct flight
from (
  select t.*, 
    count(distinct action) over (partition by flight, to_char("date", 'YYYY-MM-DD')) counter
  from test t
)
where counter = 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9e1468db5949d32931458d09785daa05).
Results:

```
> | FLIGHT |
> | -----: |
> |   1234 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to use the `join` with flight number and date as follows:

```
SELECT distinct d.flight
  FROM test d JOIN test a 
    ON d.action = 'Departure'
    AND trunc(d.date) = trunc(a.date)
    AND a.action = 'Arrival'
    AND a.flight = d.flight;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

A PIVOT statement could work too

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT flight, date, action
    FROM test)

PIVOT
    (
      MAX(DATE)
      FOR ACTION IN ('Departure' AS DEP, 'Arrival' AS AR)
    )WHERE TRUNC(DEP) = TRUNC(AR)
```