# Check that a query contains all the values of a subquery in oracle

Tags: oracle, subquery

Imagine that you have a query and you want to only show that one who has ALL the values of a subquery. For example, we have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
code VARCHAR2(4),
year VARCHAR2(4),
action VARCHAR2(50),
CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (code, year)
);
```

And the following registers:

```
INSERT INTO test
VALUES ('1','2020','Departure');
INSERT INTO test
VALUES ('1','2021','Arrival');

INSERT INTO test
VALUES ('2','2020','Departure');
```

Imagine that a subquery returns me the following values:

```
('Departure','Arrival')
```

So I want to make a query that returns me only those codes and years which match both of the values that have been returned at the subquery. Looking at the registers, it should return only return ('1','2020') and ('1','2021') because they are the only ones whose actions are 'Arrival' and 'Departure'. How could I do it?

Comment: Did you try your code anywhere? If code is a PK, how come you have 2 rows with code='1'? Should the data be on 2 rows, or just one is good enough? (e.g. in your data, if we omit the PK issue, should it return 1, 2020,2021  in one row, or 1,2020  and 1,2021 in 2 rows?

Comment: Sorry, just corrected it

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit expanded sample data, where `CODE`s 1 and 3 have both Arrival and Departure:

```
SQL> with test (code, year, action) as
  2    (select 1, 2020, 'Departure' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 2021, 'Arrival'   from dual union all
  4     select 2, 2020, 'Departure' from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 3, 2018, 'Arrival'   from dual union all
  7     select 3, 2019, 'Departure' from dual
  8    ),
  9  subq as
 10    (select distinct action,
 11            count(distinct action) over () cnt_da
 12     from test
 13    )
 14  select a.code, a.year
 15  from test a join subq s on a.action = s.action
 16  where s.cnt_da = (select count(distinct action)
 17                    from test b
 18                    where b.code = a.code
 19                   );

      CODE       YEAR
---------- ----------
         1       2021
         1       2020
         3       2019
         3       2018

SQL>
```

---

Yet another option, using the `MINUS` set operator:

```
SQL> with test (code, year, action) as
  2    (select 1, 2020, 'Departure' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 2021, 'Arrival'   from dual union all
  4     select 2, 2020, 'Departure' from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 3, 2018, 'Arrival'   from dual union all
  7     select 3, 2019, 'Departure' from dual
  8    ),
  9  subq as
 10    (select distinct action from test)       --> this is your "subquery"
 11  select code, year
 12  from test a
 13  where (select s.action from subq s
 14         minus
 15         select b.action from test b where b.code = a.code
 16        ) is null;

      CODE       YEAR
---------- ----------
         1       2020
         1       2021
         3       2018
         3       2019

SQL>
```

Comment: But that query is counting and comparing the results. I want it to literally compare them.

Comment: I added another option; have a look, please.

Comment: the OP has deleted his/her account after getting the answers. I think that this is the 2nd time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464317/query-in-oracle-to-select-with-subquery

Comment: Oh. That's impolite. Thank you, @forpas, I'll try to remember to avoid "Arrivals & Departures" questions in the future.

Comment: Then you should avoid this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681353/query-to-see-the-max-value-in-oracle

Comment: Saw it already & successfully skipped this time, @forpas. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As a general solution, I'd look for an opportunity to use `HAVING count(*) = #`.  Roughly,

> SELECT code FROM table WHERE action in (SUBSELECT) GROUP BY code HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*) from SUBSELECT)

Of course if you can have multiple `Arrival` for a single `code`, you have to include a `DISTINCT` as well.  Roughly,

> SELECT code FROM (SELECT code, distinct(action) FROM table) WHERE action in...

I worry about the performance of a query like this, but you'd have to check it in situ since most database engines have the ability to transform complex queries like this for efficiency.

===

I think a JOIN will also work if you're sure that there's only one action of each type per code.  For example.

> SELECT t.code FROM SUBQUERY as s RIGHT JOIN table as t on t.action = s.action GROUP by t.code HAVING count(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SUBQUERY)

(and yes in either case, you should use CTE features like @forpas suggests if you're going to inline the subquery to avoid repeatedly executing it).

Comment: Yes, but this is just an example of 2 values. Imagine the same situation but instead of 'Arrival' and 'Departure', it has 400 values in the subquery.

Comment: Sorry.  Fixed it to use `=` not `>`.  Logically the proposal still works.  You want any object that has all 400 rows from the filter.

Comment: I mean, that sentence is only going to check that the number of matches are the same, but it doesn't check that they are literally the same. For example, if the subquery returns 2 values ('Hello' and 'Bye') and the registers has 2 values too ('Hello' and 'Hello2') it would show that code, because they both have 2 values.

Comment: No.  The section `WHERE action in (SUBSELECT)` ensures that we only consider rows that have an action in your list.

Comment: Yeah, but if only one of those are IN the subselect, it will return true. What we are looking for is to check that ALL of the actions are in the subquery.

Comment: The `WHERE` ensures that your only counting matches.  The `HAVING` ensures that all matches exist.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your query inside a CTE like this:

```
with cte as (
  <your query here>
)
select t.*
from test t 
where
  t.action in (select action from cte)
  and 
  code in (
    select code
    from test
    where action in (select action from cte)
    group by code
    having count(distinct action) = (select count(*) from cte)
  )
```

The subquery of IN returns all the codes that contain all the actions that your query returns.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a0605195b7738e2da1e12fa274be25dc).
Results:

```
> CODE | YEAR | ACTION   
> :--- | :--- | :--------
> 1    | 2021 | Arrival  
> 1    | 2020 | Departure
```

Comment: But it only checks the number of coincidences, right?

Comment: Check the demo in my answer.

Comment: No it does not check only the number of coincidences. It filters the table with `where action in select action from cte` and then counts the number of distinct of coincidences. If they are equal it means that all the values of the cte are contained for that code.